# Multiple AWS hosted zones for one domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

In AWS, are you able to create multiple hosted zones for one domain? Say I have a domain called example.com.

In one account, I create a hosted zone for example.com and add the NS record to the DNS service.

In second account, I create another hosted zone for example.com and add the NS records to the DNS service for example.com.

1) Is this possible?
2) If it is, do I need to keep the record sets in the both hosted zones in sync with each other?

Comment: It is possible, but what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Creating multiple hosted zones allows you to verify your DNS setting in a “test” environment, and then replicate those settings on a “production” hosted zone. For example, hosted zone Z1234 might be your test version of example.com, hosted on name servers ns-1, ns-2, ns-3, and ns-4. Similarly, hosted zone Z5678 might be your production version of example.com, hosted on ns-5, ns-6, ns-7, and ns-8. Since each hosted zone has a virtual set of name servers associated with that zone, Route 53 will answer DNS queries for example.com differently depending on which name server you send the DNS query to.